# How to implement Drop pin animation in android using google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to implement dropping pins animation to markers as the one in iPhone. The problem is pins are not dropping the way they should as they are in this link : 
http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2010/12/map-markers-they-move.html
 . 
I've added the code of my example.
  Please help in implementing the animation.

```
public class MyMapAnimation extends MapActivity {
private MapView map = null;
private MyLocationOverlay me = null;
ImageView imageView = null;
Projection proj = null;
private Drawable marker;
private ArrayList<OverlayItem> itemsArrayList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Log.i("NooYawk","onCreate");

    itemsArrayList = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    itemsArrayList.add(new OverlayItem(getPoint(40.748963847316034,
            -73.96807193756104), "UN", "United Nations"));
    itemsArrayList.add(new OverlayItem(getPoint(40.76866299974387,
            -73.98268461227417), "Lincoln Center",
            "Home of Jazz at Lincoln Center"));

    itemsArrayList.add(new OverlayItem(getPoint(40.765136435316755,
            -73.97989511489868), "Carnegie Hall",
            "Where you go with practice, practice, practice"));
    itemsArrayList.add(new OverlayItem(getPoint(40.70686417491799,
            -74.01572942733765), "The Downtown Club",
            "Original home of the Heisman Trophy"));

    map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);


    map.getController().setCenter(getPoint(40.748963847316034,
     -73.96807193756104));
/*  map.getController().setCenter(
            getPoint(40.748963847316034, -73.96807193756104));*/
    map.getController().setZoom(12);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    marker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);

    proj = map.getProjection();
    imageView = new ImageView(this);

    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.marker);

    marker.setBounds(0, 0, marker.getIntrinsicWidth(),
            marker.getIntrinsicHeight());


    map.getOverlays().add(new SitesOverlay(marker));

    me = new MyLocationOverlay(this, map);
    map.getOverlays().add(me);

    /*
     * map.getController().animateTo( getPoint(40.748963847316034,
     * -73.96807193756104));
     */

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    me.enableCompass();
    Log.i("NooYawk","onResume");
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.i("NooYawk","onPause");
    me.disableCompass();
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    Log.i("NooYawk","isRouteDisplayed");
    return (false);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_S) {
        map.setSatellite(!map.isSatellite());
        return (true);
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_Z) {
        map.displayZoomControls(true);
        return (true);
    }

    return (super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event));
}

private GeoPoint getPoint(double lat, double lon) {
    Log.i("NooYawk","getPoint");
    return (new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1000000.0), (int) (lon * 1000000.0)));
}

private class SitesOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
    private List<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    private Drawable marker = null;
    private OverlayItem inDrag = null;
    private ImageView dragImage = null;
    private int xDragImageOffset = 0;
    private int yDragImageOffset = 0;
    private int xDragTouchOffset = 0;
    private int yDragTouchOffset = 0;
    Point p = new Point(0, 0);
    private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    private ArrayList<ImageView> imageViewArrayList;

    public SitesOverlay(Drawable marker) {
        super(marker);
        this.marker = marker;



        Log.i("NooYawk","SitesOverlay");
 dragImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.drag);



        Log.d("POint",
                ""
                        + (map.getProjection().toPixels(
                                getPoint(40.748963847316034,
                                        -73.96807193756104), p).x)
                        + ","
                        + (map.getProjection().toPixels(
                                getPoint(40.748963847316034,
                                        -73.96807193756104), p).y));

        TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = null;

        imageViewArrayList = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
        for (OverlayItem currentOverlayItem : itemsArrayList) {
            Log.i("NooYawk","currentOverlayItem");
            imageView = new ImageView(NooYawk.this);

            imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.marker);

            relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_map_main);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            param.leftMargin = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                    .getWidth() / 2;
            param.topMargin = 0;

            relativeLayout.addView(imageView, param);
            imageViewArrayList.add(imageView);
        }
        int count = 0;
        Log.i("x for translate before animation",
                (map.getProjection().toPixels(
                        itemsArrayList.get(0).getPoint(), p).x)+"");
        for (ImageView currentImageView : imageViewArrayList) {
            Log.i("NooYawk","currentImageView");
            translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation((map
                    .getProjection().toPixels(
                            itemsArrayList.get(count).getPoint(), p).x),
                    (map.getProjection().toPixels(
                            itemsArrayList.get(count).getPoint(), p).x), 0,
                    (map.getProjection().toPixels(
                            itemsArrayList.get(count).getPoint(), p).y));


            translateAnimation.setDuration(2000);
            currentImageView.startAnimation(translateAnimation);
            count++;
        }

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {


            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.i("NooYawk","run");
                // relativeLayout.removeView(imageView);
                for (ImageView currentImageView : imageViewArrayList) {
                    Log.i("NooYawk","thread : currentImageView");
                    currentImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                setItemValues();
                populate();

                Log.i("x for translate after animation",
                        (map.getProjection().toPixels(
                                itemsArrayList.get(0).getPoint(), p).x)+"");
            }
        }, translateAnimation.getDuration());

    }

    private void setItemValues() {
        int count = 0;
        Log.i("NooYawk","setItemVAlues");
        for (OverlayItem currentOverlayItem : itemsArrayList) {
            items.add(currentOverlayItem);

            Log.i("items ", items.get(count).getPoint()+"");
            count++;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        Log.i("NooYawk","createitem");
        return (items.get(i));
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        // items.get(0)
        Log.i("NooYawk","draw");
         boundCenterBottom(marker); 

    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        Log.i("NooYawk","size");
        return (items.size());
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Is your issue resolved?
If yes then how had you done that?
Can you please share as I am also looking for a similar type of animation.
Can it be possible to develop such type of animation using JavaScript and how do we use JavaScript in a native Android application?

Comment: follow this link... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607042/tutorial-android-map-pin-drop-animation-working-right

Comment: I've used Scott's answer, and it does the job pretty well

Answer (score 3):

*I am posting the core concept that is working to have the drop pin animation in mapView as that of iPhopne.*
**Same can be integrated with overlays also....**

```
Drawable drawableImage = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
myCustomOverlay = new CustomOverlay(drawableImage, mapView);
initGeoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (latitudeArray[i] * 1E6),(int) (longitudeArray[i] * 1E6));
OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(initGeoPoint,getLocationAddress(latitudeArray[i], longitudeArray[i]),"xyz");

myCustomOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
mapOverlays.add(myCustomOverlay);

RelativeLayout v = (RelativeLayout) View.inflate(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.marker_layout, null);
ImageView markerView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.marker_img_view);
AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(true);

TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, -400.0f, 0.0f);
translateAnimation.setDuration(1000);
animation.addAnimation(translateAnimation);

markerView.startAnimation(animation);

mapView.addView(v, 
      new MapView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT), 
      new GeoPoint((int) (latitude * 1E6),(int) (longitude * 1E6)),
      MapView.LayoutParams.BOTTOM_CENTER));

mapView.invalidate();
```

marker_layout is as folows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/marker_img_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/marker" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Overlay Class ###########

```
public class CustomOverlay extends BalloonItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> m_overlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    private Context c;

    public CustomOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, MapView mapView) {
        super(boundCenter(defaultMarker), mapView);
        c = mapView.getContext();
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        m_overlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
        if (!shadow) {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, false);
        }
    }

    public void removeOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        m_overlays.remove(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return m_overlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return m_overlays.size();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onBalloonTap(int index, OverlayItem item) {
        Toast.makeText(
                c,
                "onBalloonTap for overlay index " + index + " Item"
                        + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        String id = "";

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any example of how to integrate this with Overlays? As far as I can determine, overlays are not views, but objects.

Comment: You can add the Overlays to geo loaction.. Also you can show the overlays on finish of drop animation... Just to have the pin animation we have used the view.. But the sole would be the Overlays itself.These are not shown in the code

Answer (score 1):

The best way to animate items on the MapView is not using Views, but animating the overlay.

Here's a class I made to handle animating map markers to replicate the behaviour of the nice effect you get on the iPhone. In this case I was adding markers to indicate businesses so where it says 'Business' it is just referring to a marker. This code hasn't been tested on many devices. I know there can be some issues with the projection class which might cause issues so don't take this code as stable and treat accordingly.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.Projection;

public class MarkerOverlay extends Overlay {
    private ArrayList<Business> mOverlays = new ArrayList<Business>();
    private Bitmap mBitmapMarker;
    private Bitmap mBitmapShadow;

    DropMarkersTask animateMarkers;
    OnItemClickListener itemClickedListener;

    public MarkerOverlay(Bitmap defaultMarker) {
        mBitmapMarker = defaultMarker;

        // Create shadow bitmap. Basically a black version of the image
        mBitmapShadow = defaultMarker.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        for(int x = 0;x < mBitmapShadow.getWidth();x++)
            for(int y = 0;y < mBitmapShadow.getHeight();y++)
                if(mBitmapShadow.getPixel(x, y) != Color.TRANSPARENT) // This is a little lazy but it works
                    mBitmapShadow.setPixel(x, y, Color.BLACK);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener clickListener) {
        this.itemClickedListener = clickListener;
    }

    public void addBusiness(Business overlay) {
        for(Business business : mOverlays) {
            if(overlay.getPoint().getLatitudeE6() == business.getPoint().getLatitudeE6() && 
                    overlay.getPoint().getLongitudeE6() == overlay.getPoint().getLongitudeE6()) {
                // Don't add any markers which exist at exactly the same location, chances are it's the same marker
                return;
            } else if (overlay.getPoint().getLatitudeE6() > business.getPoint().getLatitudeE6()) {
                // This is so all the markers are listed top to bottom
                mOverlays.add(mOverlays.indexOf(business), overlay);
                return;
            }
        }
        mOverlays.add(overlay);
    }

    public Business getItem(int position) {
        return mOverlays.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {

        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
        boolean animationRequired = false;

        // Find the bounds in which the markers must reside to be displayed
        GeoPoint bottomLeft = projection.fromPixels(- mBitmapMarker.getWidth() / 2, mapView.getHeight() + mBitmapMarker.getHeight());
        GeoPoint topRight = projection.fromPixels(mapView.getWidth() + mBitmapMarker.getWidth() / 2, 0);

        for(Business business : mOverlays) {
            // Check to ensure the marker is inside the bounds
            if(business.getPoint().getLatitudeE6() > bottomLeft.getLatitudeE6() && business.getPoint().getLatitudeE6() < topRight.getLatitudeE6() 
                    && business.getPoint().getLongitudeE6() > bottomLeft.getLongitudeE6() && business.getPoint().getLongitudeE6() < topRight.getLongitudeE6()) {
                if(business.isNewPoint()) {
                    business.setOffset(mapView.getHeight());
                    business.setOldPoint();
                }
                Point pt = new Point();
                projection.toPixels(business.getPoint() ,pt);

                if(shadow) {
                    // Set the location of the shadow according to the offset so it appears to come in from the top right
                    pt.x = pt.x + (mBitmapMarker.getWidth() / 4) + ((int)business.getOffset() / 2);
                    pt.y = pt.y - (mBitmapMarker.getHeight() / 2) - ((int)business.getOffset() / 2);

                    // Skew the shadow and set the location
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    matrix.preSkew(-0.8f, 0f);
                    matrix.preScale(1f, 0.5f);
                    matrix.postTranslate(pt.x, pt.y);

                    // Change transparency according to the offset
                    Paint paint = new Paint();
                    paint.setAlpha((int)(((mapView.getHeight() - business.getOffset()) / mapView.getHeight()) * 100));

                    // Draw it
                    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapShadow, matrix, paint);
                } else {
                    // Set the position according to the offset
                    pt.x = pt.x - (mBitmapMarker.getWidth() / 2);
                    pt.y = pt.y - mBitmapMarker.getHeight() - (int)business.getOffset();

                    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapMarker, (float)pt.x, (float)pt.y, null);

                    if(business.getOffset() > 0) {
                        animationRequired = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Start the animation task if it hasn't already been started
        if(animationRequired && (animateMarkers == null || animateMarkers.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)) {
            animateMarkers = new DropMarkersTask();
            animateMarkers.execute(mapView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTap(GeoPoint point, MapView map) {
        if(itemClickedListener == null) {
            return false;
        }

        Projection projection = map.getProjection();
        int imageWidth = mBitmapMarker.getWidth();
        int imageHeight = mBitmapMarker.getHeight();

        // Find the point on the screen which has been clicked
        Point clickPoint = new Point();
        projection.toPixels(point, clickPoint);

        // Go backwards through the businesses and find out if the location falls within their marker
        for(int i = mOverlays.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            Business business = mOverlays.get(i);
            Point businessPoint = new Point();
            projection.toPixels(business.getPoint(), businessPoint);
            if(businessPoint.x > 0 && businessPoint.x < map.getWidth() &&
                    businessPoint.y > 0 && businessPoint.y < map.getHeight()) {
                // Point is visible, so may clicked
                int left = businessPoint.x - (imageWidth / 2);
                int right = businessPoint.x + (imageWidth / 2);
                int top = businessPoint.y - imageHeight;
                int bottom = businessPoint.y;

                if(clickPoint.x >= left && clickPoint.x <= right && clickPoint.y >= top && clickPoint.y <= bottom) { // Item has been clicked                   
                    // Adapter will be null as this isn't one. We will return the map 
                    // in the view for consistency but most importantly the index of the item
                    itemClickedListener.onItemClick(null, map, i, 0);
                    return true;
                }
            }

        }

        return false;
    }

    class DropMarkersTask extends AsyncTask<MapView, Void, Void> {
        MapView mapView;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(MapView... mapViews) {
            mapView = mapViews[0];
            boolean mapUpdate = true;

            try {
                while(mapUpdate) {
                    Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
                    GeoPoint bottomLeft = projection.fromPixels(- mBitmapMarker.getWidth() / 2, mapView.getHeight() + mBitmapMarker.getHeight());
                    GeoPoint topRight = projection.fromPixels(mapView.getWidth() + mBitmapMarker.getWidth() / 2, 0);
                    mapUpdate = false;

                    // Any visible markers with an offset higher than zero must be falling and therefore must be moved.
                    for(Business business : mOverlays) {
                        if(business.getPoint().getLatitudeE6() > bottomLeft.getLatitudeE6() && business.getPoint().getLatitudeE6() < topRight.getLatitudeE6() 
                                && business.getPoint().getLongitudeE6() > bottomLeft.getLongitudeE6() && business.getPoint().getLongitudeE6() < topRight.getLongitudeE6()) {
                            if(business.getOffset() > 0) {
                                // A nice Quadratic fall curve.
                                double currentY = Math.sqrt(mapView.getHeight() - business.getOffset());
                                currentY = currentY + 0.5;
                                double dropDistance = Math.pow(currentY, 2);
                                double newOffset = mapView.getHeight() - dropDistance;
                                if(newOffset < 0) { // Marker can't have an offset less than zero
                                    newOffset = 0;
                                }
                                business.setOffset(newOffset);
                                mapUpdate = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if(mapUpdate) {
                        this.publishProgress();
                        Thread.sleep(20);
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... unused) {
            mapView.postInvalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

Setting up the overlay (most likely in your onCreate method):

```
    mapBusinesses = (EventMapView)findViewById(R.id.mapBusinesses);

    mapOverlays = mapBusinesses.getOverlays();

    Bitmap drawable = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.map_pin);
    businessMarkerOverlay = new MarkerOverlay(drawable);
    businessMarkerOverlay.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
            Business business = businessMarkerOverlay.getItem(position);
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.class);
            dialog.setTitle(business.getBusiness());
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
    mapOverlays.add(businessMarkerOverlay);
```

Adding a new marker:
Don't forget to call postInvalidate on the map to kick off the first draw when the map it otherwise idle.

```
businessMarkerOverlay.addBusiness(business);
mapBusinesses.postInvalidate();
```

Lastly, this is the class I used for the Business object:

```
public class Business {
    private String _business;
    private int _businessId;
    private GeoPoint _point;

    private boolean _newPoint;
    private double _offset;

    public Business(GeoPoint point, String business, int businessId) {
        _point = point;
        _business = business;
        _businessId = businessId;
        _newPoint = true;
    }

    public int getBusinessId() { return _businessId; }
    public String getBusiness() { return _business; }
    public GeoPoint getPoint() { return _point; }
    public boolean isNewPoint() { return _newPoint; }
    public double getOffset() { return _offset; }

    public void setOldPoint() { _newPoint = false; }
    public void setOffset(double offset) { _offset = offset; }
}
```

Comment: You should use pixels to check bounds. Not Lat/Long. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Scott. I love your example but you have bounds calculation a little bit off.

Here's how it should be.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.Projection;

public class MarkerOverlay extends Overlay {
    private ArrayList<Business> mOverlays = new ArrayList<Business>();
    private Bitmap mBitmapMarker;
    private Bitmap mBitmapShadow;

    DropMarkersTask animateMarkers;
    OnItemClickListener itemClickedListener;

    public MarkerOverlay(Bitmap defaultMarker) {
        mBitmapMarker = defaultMarker;

        // Create shadow bitmap. Basically a black version of the image
        mBitmapShadow = defaultMarker.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        for(int x = 0;x < mBitmapShadow.getWidth();x++)
            for(int y = 0;y < mBitmapShadow.getHeight();y++)
                if(mBitmapShadow.getPixel(x, y) != Color.TRANSPARENT) // This is a little lazy but it works
                    mBitmapShadow.setPixel(x, y, Color.BLACK);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener clickListener) {
        this.itemClickedListener = clickListener;
    }

    public void addBusiness(Business overlay) {
        for(Business business : mOverlays) {
            if(overlay.getPoint().getLatitudeE6() == business.getPoint().getLatitudeE6() && 
                    overlay.getPoint().getLongitudeE6() == overlay.getPoint().getLongitudeE6()) {
                // Don't add any markers which exist at exactly the same location, chances are it's the same marker
                return;
            } else if (overlay.getPoint().getLatitudeE6() > business.getPoint().getLatitudeE6()) {
                // This is so all the markers are listed top to bottom
                mOverlays.add(mOverlays.indexOf(business), overlay);
                return;
            }
        }
        mOverlays.add(overlay);
    }

    public Business getItem(int position) {
        return mOverlays.get(position);
    }

    public static Rect getMapDrawingRect(MapView mapView, Bitmap marker) {
        Rect mapDrawRect = new Rect();
        mapView.getDrawingRect(mapDrawRect);
        mapDrawRect.left = mapDrawRect.left - marker.getWidth(); // full marker width to include shadow
        mapDrawRect.right = mapDrawRect.right + marker.getWidth()/2; 
        mapDrawRect.bottom = mapDrawRect.bottom + marker.getHeight(); // full height of marker
        return mapDrawRect;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

        Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
        boolean animationRequired = false;

        Rect mapDrawRect = getMapDrawingRect(mapView, mBitmapMarker);
        for(Business business : mOverlays) {
            Point outPoint = new Point();
            projection.toPixels(business.getPoint(), outPoint);
            if (!mapDrawRect.contains(outPoint.x, outPoint.y)) {
                continue;
            }

            if(business.isNewPoint()) {
                business.setOffset(mapView.getHeight());
                business.setOldPoint();
            }
            Point pt = new Point();
            projection.toPixels(business.getPoint() ,pt);

            if(shadow) {
                // Set the location of the shadow according to the offset so it appears to come in from the top right
                pt.x = pt.x + (mBitmapMarker.getWidth() / 4) + ((int)business.getOffset() / 2);
                pt.y = pt.y - (mBitmapMarker.getHeight() / 2) - ((int)business.getOffset() / 2);

                // Skew the shadow and set the location
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.preSkew(-0.8f, 0f);
                matrix.preScale(1f, 0.5f);
                matrix.postTranslate(pt.x, pt.y);

                // Change transparency according to the offset
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setAlpha((int)(((mapView.getHeight() - business.getOffset()) / mapView.getHeight()) * 100));

                // Draw it
                canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapShadow, matrix, paint);
            } else {
                // Set the position according to the offset
                pt.x = pt.x - (mBitmapMarker.getWidth() / 2);
                pt.y = pt.y - mBitmapMarker.getHeight() - (int)business.getOffset();

                canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapMarker, (float)pt.x, (float)pt.y, null);
                if(business.getOffset() > 0) {
                    animationRequired = true;
                }
            }
        }

        // Start the animation task if it hasn't already been started
        if(animationRequired && (animateMarkers == null || animateMarkers.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)) {
            animateMarkers = new DropMarkersTask();
            animateMarkers.execute(mapView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTap(GeoPoint point, MapView map) {
        if(itemClickedListener == null) {
            return false;
        }

        Projection projection = map.getProjection();
        int imageWidth = mBitmapMarker.getWidth();
        int imageHeight = mBitmapMarker.getHeight();

        // Find the point on the screen which has been clicked
        Point clickPoint = new Point();
        projection.toPixels(point, clickPoint);

        // Go backwards through the businesses and find out if the location falls within their marker
        for(int i = mOverlays.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            Business business = mOverlays.get(i);
            Point businessPoint = new Point();
            projection.toPixels(business.getPoint(), businessPoint);
            if(businessPoint.x > 0 && businessPoint.x < map.getWidth() &&
                    businessPoint.y > 0 && businessPoint.y < map.getHeight()) {
                // Point is visible, so may clicked
                int left = businessPoint.x - (imageWidth / 2);
                int right = businessPoint.x + (imageWidth / 2);
                int top = businessPoint.y - imageHeight;
                int bottom = businessPoint.y;

                if(clickPoint.x >= left && clickPoint.x <= right && clickPoint.y >= top && clickPoint.y <= bottom) { // Item has been clicked                   
                    // Adapter will be null as this isn't one. We will return the map 
                    // in the view for consistency but most importantly the index of the item
                    itemClickedListener.onItemClick(null, map, i, 0);
                    return true;
                }
            }

        }

        return false;
    }

    class DropMarkersTask extends AsyncTask<MapView, Void, Void> {
        MapView mapView;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(MapView... mapViews) {
            mapView = mapViews[0];
            boolean mapUpdate = true;

            try {
                while(mapUpdate) {
                    Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
                    Rect mapDrawRect = getMapDrawingRect(mapView, mBitmapMarker);
                    mapUpdate = false;

                    // Any visible markers with an offset higher than zero must be falling and therefore must be moved.
                    for(Business business : mOverlays) {
                        Point outPoint = new Point();
                        projection.toPixels(business.getPoint(), outPoint);
                        if (!mapDrawRect.contains(outPoint.x, outPoint.y)) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        if(business.getOffset() > 0) {
                            // A nice Quadratic fall curve.
                            double currentY = Math.sqrt(mapView.getHeight() - business.getOffset());
                            currentY = currentY + 0.5;
                            double dropDistance = Math.pow(currentY, 2);
                            double newOffset = mapView.getHeight() - dropDistance;
                            if(newOffset < 0) { // Marker can't have an offset less than zero
                                newOffset = 0;
                            }
                            business.setOffset(newOffset);
                            mapUpdate = true;
                        }
                    }

                    if(mapUpdate) {
                        this.publishProgress();
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... unused) {
            mapView.postInvalidate();
        }
    }
}
```